# How can I attach a file to a message?

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to forward a file to the mentioned user when using the command, the problem is that I don't know how to do it.

```js
if (command === "file") {
    if (message.channel.id != "700038969253167125") return;
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(`> <@${message.author.id}> ✅`)

    let filejoin = args.join(" ");
    if (!filejoin)

        client.channels.cache.get('700052786909282344').send(`:information_source: **|** Ha llegado un nuevo archivo (<@${message.author.id}>)\n\n"${filejoin}"`);
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    client.channels.cache.get('700052786909282344').send(`:information_source: **|** Ha llegado un nuevo archivo (<@${message.author.id}>)\n\n"${filejoin}"`).then(async m => {

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send files using the [`.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method.

As you stated in the comments of this answer, you want the file attached to the message containing the command to be sent to you. You can do that like so:

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get("YOUR_ID")
if (message.attachments.array().length) {
   message.attachments.forEach((attachment) => user.send({ files: [ attachment ] }))
   user.send(`These files were sent by ${message.author.tag}`)
}
```

Comment: Okay, but in case you need to use the arguments? that's my main problem..

Comment: This is not how I say it is, I'm referring is if a user sends a file, I want the bot forward that file with the content of the file.

If the user send with the !file command with an document called hi.docx as an example, the bot would forward that document, with the content (Without modifying nothing)

The thing you sent me, is that an .txt file being renamed to the arg that the user mentioned before

Comment: You need to be clear when asking questions, I edited my answer, that should work now.

Comment: What language do you speak?

Comment: Thank you! On the one hand it has served, on the other hand a new problem has emerged, now the message to the MD of the user assigned in "profesor" sends it, but it does not send the attachment that the one that executed the command! Task I send ... only the message that was assigned.

[This is the error I get on the console](https://hastebin.com/micimidezu.coffeescript)

By the way, excuse my writing and little explanation, it is that I still do not speak English and that is why I use Translator, nor is it that I know much about this from the forums. Speak Spanish.

Comment: I just edited my answer, it should work now, sorry about that. Also, next time maybe try the Spanish Stack Overflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/